# SignalR with web Api as client [.Net Core]

Tags: .net-core, signalr, signalr.client

I have a signalR server working Ok, and some clients (front-end pages) receiving correctly the messages or events from the server.

But, now one of the clients is a web api. But I'm not sure about how to make the corresponding configurations to achieve the goal that the web api keeps on listening and receiving calls from the server signalR.

Note: SignalR server and clients are on .Net Core.

I've looked for this scenario but I've not got it.

One example of some kind "similar" is this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) from Microsoft, but this is with a windows form. So, I'm kinda lost.

Anyone have some ideas about how to get it? I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to use that Microsoft example, but implement it as a Background Service. You just implement the Background Service with `SignalR.Client` package and run in on the startup. Then you will have a service that is listening to the SignalR calls.

```cs
services.AddHostedService<SignalRService>();
```

```cs
public sealed class SignalRService : BackgroundService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the background service.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">
    /// The cancellation token. This token signals that the background service is being stopped.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>The <see cref="Task"/> that represents the asynchronous operation.</returns>
    /// <remarks>This method is automatically triggered after the background service is started.</remarks>
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // your SignalR code
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Kiril1512, Thanks so much. This was the solution